# Are there non-abelian totally real extensions?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

I'm aware that abelian extensions are either totally real or CM.

Also, Galois extension are either totally real o totally imaginary.

But I'm wondering about the *converses* to those statements.

- **Are all totally real extensions abelian?** (a counterexample would be great)
- **Are all CM-extensions abelian?** (the samea applies)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If a Galois extension has Galois group of odd order, then it must be totally real, since the Galois group can't contain complex conjugation. And certainly there should be Galois extensions with nonabelian Galois groups of odd order, the smallest example being the Frobenius group of order $21$.

Comment: Another example, not nearly as cute: take $\sqrt{5+\sqrt2}$, generates a nonnormal totally real extension, so the Galois group has to be nonabelian.

Comment: As for your second question, pick your favorite answer given to the first question, and adjoin $i$ to it.  The new Galois group will have the old one as a quotient, making it nonabelian.

Comment: Just for the avoidance of doubt it should be pointed out that all of the above statements (and indeed the entire question) assume implicitly that we are talking about (number field) extensions of $\mathbb{Q}$, and NOT of a general number field ....