# Simple Galois extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, galois-extensions

> Let $\alpha$ be a algebraic real number over $\mathbb{Q}$, and let $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ be a Galois over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Then, what can we say about the properties of its Galois group $\textrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q})$?

For example:

1) $\textrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q})$ is abelian.

2) There is a non-abelian group $\textrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q})$ under the hypothesis.

I can't find the latter case. Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_element_theorem#Classical_Primitive_Element_Theorem

in particular every finite extension over $\mathbb Q$ is simple. Now take your favourite non-abelian extension.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1477380/are-there-non-abelian-totally-real-extensions the comments here should answer your question

Comment: For 2) see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1810418/nonabelian-galois-group) (and others).